# Angular select options with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I'm struggled for few days now with ngOptions, ngRepeat. I have to do something like select option of people control. My REST service is giving me something like array in snippet below. I tried every stackoverflow answer and example from Angular documentation. No results. I can't even show a single attribute  - wham am i doing wrong?

There is some tries below.

Thanks for any advice and help.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.players = [{"id": "1", "nickName" : "Cole", "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Coleman"}, {"id" : "2", "nickName" : "West", "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName" : "West"}];

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form>
        <label>Captain:
            <select ng-model="team.captain">
                <option ng-repeat="player in players" value="{{player.id}}"> {{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}}</option>
            </select>
        </label><br />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to register you controller in your app: `angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);`

Then in the template in html set `<html ng-app="myApp"></html>`.

And then in template specify controller which controlls desired piece of template like `<form ng-controller='MyCtrl'>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm ng-app="myApp">


<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl">
..            <select ng-model="team.captain">
                <option ng-repeat="player in players" value="{{player.id}}"> {{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}}</option>
            </select>
     </form>
  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.players = [{"id": "1", "nickName" : "Cole", "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Coleman"}, {"id" : "2", "nickName" : "West", "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName" : "West"}];

}

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to register controller for `myApp` module

like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.players = [{"id": "1", "nickName" : "Cole", "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Coleman"}, {"id" : "2", "nickName" : "West", "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName" : "West"}];

}
```

and in html you should use `ng-app="myApp"` and `ng-controller="myCtrl"`

like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp"> //used module

  <head>
    // load your script here
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl"> // used controller
    <form>
        <label>Captain:
            <select ng-model="team.captain">
              <option value ="">select one</option>
              <option ng-repeat="player in players" value="{{player.id}}"> {{player.firstName}} {{player.lastName}}</option>
            </select>
        </label><br />
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

[PLUNKER DEMO LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/3GYvqr3dzEbqGVzgStRp?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**, Try This one :

**APP.JS CODE**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.players = [{"id": "1", "nickName" : "Cole", "firstName" : "Mark", "lastName" : "Coleman"}, {"id" : "2", "nickName" : "West", "firstName" : "Peter", "lastName" : "West"}];
    $scope.selected = $scope.players[0];
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<select ng-options="player as player.nickName for player in players ng-model="selected"></select>
```

1. Working Fiddle Here of your code : [Select in AngularJs Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amulya9292/bjs3g/72/)

**Thanks & Cheers**